# Stalks of Composition of Morphisms of Presheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G}, \mathscr{H}$ be presheaves of Abelian groups on $X$. My question is that if $\phi :\mathscr{F} \rightarrow \mathscr{G}$, $\psi :\mathscr{G} \rightarrow \mathscr{H}$ are morphisms and $P \in X$, does $(\psi \circ \phi)_P = \psi_P \circ \phi_P$ hold?

> My Approach :
>
> Each element in $\mathscr{F}_P$ can be written by $s_P$ for some local section $s \in \mathscr{F}(U)$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $P$. By definition, we have
>
> $(\psi \circ \phi)_P(s_P) = [(\psi \circ \phi)(U)(s)]_P = [(\psi(U) \circ \phi(U))(s)]_P = \psi_P([\phi(U)(s)]_P) = \psi_P(\phi_P(s_P))$

I ask this question because I could find this formula in any (I known) textbook for algebraic geometry (is that too trivial? or just wrong?). Could someone tell me whether my arguments is true or not? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes your argument is fine. Most of the book don't say it explicitly but may say that taking stalks is a functor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your answer solve my confusion for stalks of morphisms.